# Wordpress add menu items display slug too

Tags: categories, admin-menu

Using the Wordpress menu system to add an item (product category in my case). I have categories with the same name, under a different parent category, so when i search for the category i want it may display 3-4 categories with the same name.
*in the image example i have changed the names to better understand what is what.

[image]

Is there a way to add the slug after the product category in the menu system (primarily in Search tab but if possible in Most Used & View All tabs too).

Something like:

```
ARMANI (armani-woman)
ARMANI (armani-man)
ARMANI (armani-lotion)
```

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, you can use [the `wp_setup_nav_menu_item` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_setup_nav_menu_item/) to change properties of the nav menu item:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', static function ( $menu_item ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() || empty( $menu_item->taxonomy ) || 'category' !== $menu_item->taxonomy ) {
        return $menu_item;
    }

    $menu_item->title .= sprintf( ' (%s)', $menu_item->slug );

    return $menu_item;
} );
```

[image: nav menu Categories box with slugs]

The above approach may have unintended consequences, and pollutes the list of terms. A cleaner approach would be to intercept the AJAX call and implement your own search logic:

```php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_menu-quick-search', static function () {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {
        wp_die( -1 );
    }

    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php';

    $request = $_POST;

    $args            = array();
    $type            = isset( $request['type'] ) ? $request['type'] : '';
    $object_type     = isset( $request['object_type'] ) ? $request['object_type'] : '';
    $query           = isset( $request['q'] ) ? $request['q'] : '';
    $response_format = isset( $request['response-format'] ) ? $request['response-format'] : '';

    if ( ! $response_format || ! in_array( $response_format, array( 'json', 'markup' ), true ) ) {
        $response_format = 'json';
    }

    if ( 'markup' === $response_format ) {
        $args['walker'] = new Walker_Nav_Menu_Checklist();
    }

    if ( ! preg_match( '/quick-search-(posttype|taxonomy)-([a-zA-Z_-]*\b)/', $type, $matches ) ) {
        _wp_ajax_menu_quick_search( $_POST );
        wp_die();
    }

    if ( 'taxonomy' !== $matches[1] ) {
        _wp_ajax_menu_quick_search( $_POST );
        wp_die();
    }

    // First, let's try to match our query with term's slug.
    $terms = get_terms(
        array(
            'taxonomy'   => $matches[2],
            'search'     => $query,
            'number'     => 10,
            'hide_empty' => false,
        )
    );

    // First search failed. Default to core logic: search by name.
    if ( empty( $terms ) || is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        $terms = get_terms(
            array(
                'taxonomy'   => $matches[2],
                'name__like' => $query,
                'number'     => 10,
                'hide_empty' => false,
            )
        );
    }

    if ( empty( $terms ) || is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        wp_die();
    }

    foreach ( (array) $terms as $term ) {
        if ( 'markup' === $response_format ) {
            echo walk_nav_menu_tree( array_map( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', array( $term ) ), 0, (object) $args );
        } elseif ( 'json' === $response_format ) {
            echo wp_json_encode(
                array(
                    'ID'         => $term->term_id,
                    'post_title' => $term->name,
                    'post_type'  => $matches[2],
                )
            );
            echo "\n";
        }
    }

    wp_die();
}, 0 );
```

For this approach, it copies a lot of code from WP core, so there may be incompatibilities in future versions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the first will work but only for post categories my main problem is with the products categories. The second will not work not even for post categories :( (latest version of WP & plugins)

Comment: Just confirmed: the second approach worked perfectly for post categories and WooCommerce's _Product Categories_ menu box. What did you type into the search box? The term's slug must be an exact match.

Comment: Actually, just found `search` parameter in `WP_Term_Query`, so the slug doesn't have to be an exact match.

Comment: Must be an issue with my site only will check more